# Emacs binding keys to commands

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I'm following the "trick" described here to add new key bindings to my `.emacs` file: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Binding-keys-to-commands.html

However, it's resulting in lines like this in my `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key [24 4] (quote some-command))
```

Instead of `[24 4]` I want it to explicitly mention the human-readable key commands `C-x C-d`. Otherwise when I'm looking at my `.emacs` file I can't make sense of `[24 4]` and forget what keys I've bound things to.

1) what should I replace `[24 4]` with in my `.emacs` file to make it human-readable?

2) Is there a way to use the above "trick" and have it generate the human-readable key command instead of numerals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function **key-description** to convert the sequence into a more readable form -

```
(key-description [24 4])
=> "C-x C-d"
```

and then convert it back using the function **kbd**, so you can say

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-d") 'some-command)
```

So using **kbd** you can skip the trick mentioned and just write your keybindings directly. It's a little more typing than other representations but it's definitely easier to read.

To see how to write a given key, hit **C-h c** then the key(s) - this calls describe-key-briefly and outputs something in the message area like `"M-Q runs the command fill-paragraph"` or `"<C-M-f7> is undefined"`.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs lisp, characters are written `?<char>`, and just like in C they are treated like integers, so instead of 24 you can write `?\C-x` or `?\^x` and instead of  you can write `?\C-d` or `?\^d`, so over all, I'd write it `[?\C-x ?\C-d]`.